# Best way to find background - Image processing Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, background-image

I am working on a project where I have to find the background of a given gray-scale image. 
I did several kinds of research on the internet and I've found some algorithms using OpenCV library (like the following: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html#py-background-subtraction).

This kind of approach doesn't work for me.
The image I want to elaborate is:

[image: Original]

As you can see it is in gray-scale and we see the "gray static" background. I would love to see only the nucleus of the cell (the image will improve resolution and quality in the time, this is a pretty raw one)

I tried to subtract the 2D magnitude FFT of the background from the main image but the results is not good:
[image: Final results DFT subtract]

What I am asking is: What kind of process do you suggest to use to eliminate background?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try [watershed](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html) algorithm ? I saw on a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/260677513_Improved_Watershed_Algorithm_for_Cell_Image_Segmentation) it's already used and improved for cell image segmentation.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Background subtraction won't work for your images because your background is not consistent. image's SNR is too low!

So you have 2 options:

1) Using deep learning method (like UNET) if you have enough data

2) Using bilateral filter then, some methods like active contour or GLCM Texture Feature or k-means clustering.

Comment: I've implemented bilateral filter 30min ago and it worked pretty good to noise reduction. I've tried other algorithm too. Thanks :)